# How to use SSE with multiple streams in NGRX effect

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, server-sent-events, ngrx-effects

I'm trying to subscribe to 2 server side events inside NGRX effects, then join the results into a single object and dispatch the payload in an action to the store. I'm referencing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36812714/using-rxjs-and-angular-2-in-order-to-deal-with-server-sent-events), but I havent been able to find any examples on doing this within an effect.

**1)** How can I create (2) new event sources within my effect as observables

**2)** How can I combine them into an object so that everytime my server emits the events, it waits until each has arrived and then emits the new load action with those values. I have looked into Forkjoin, MergeMap, and Zip. Zip seems the best so far since you can wait for both observables, but it still streams data in an array.

This is my current process and pseudo code:

```
@Effect()
    getTraceData = this.actions$
        .ofType(appActions.GET_PLOT_DATA)
        .pipe(
            switchMap((action$: appActions.GetPlotDataAction) => {
                    // instead of http post, return two event sources
                    // new EventSource('/data1') + new EventSource('/data2')
                    return this.http.post(
                        `http://${this.url}/low-res-data`,
                        action$.payload.getJson(),
                        { responseType: 'json', observe: 'body', headers: this.headers });
            }),
            // not sure if I should use forkJoin or MergeMap
            // to make the data = { data1, data2}
            map((plotData) => {
                return {
                        type: appActions.LOAD_PLOT_DATA_SUCCESS,
                        payload: plotData
                }
            }),
        )
```

Comment: Sounds like you just need to use the `zip` operator

Comment: hmm, that is getting there. although, then I will have to implement checks for the types, and I recall an operator that can combine streams into an object notation I just can't remember it. any ideas on adding the event source?