# ngFor not displaying data from Observable Event Source

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, ngfor, eventsource

In my Angular6 application I have a problem with displaying data with async ngfor. I am expecting some Server Sent Events from backend (just object with answer string field). While console.log shows that answer list from service contains answers, ngfor displays nothing.

Here is my component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Answer } from './answer';
import { AnswerReactiveService } from './answer-reactive.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-answers',
  templateUrl: './answers.component.html',
  providers: [AnswerReactiveService],
  styleUrls: ['./answers.component.css']
})
export class AnswersComponent {
  answers: Observable<Answer[]>;

  constructor(private answerReactiveService: AnswerReactiveService) {
  }

  requestAnswerStream(): void {
    this.answers = this.answerReactiveService.getAnswerStream();
  }

}
```

Here is the service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Answer } from './answer';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AnswerReactiveService {

  private answers: Answer[] = [];
  private url: string = 'http://localhost:8080/events/1';

  getAnswerStream(): Observable<Array<Answer>> {
    return Observable.create((observer) => {
      let url = this.url;
      let eventSource = new EventSource(url);
      eventSource.onmessage = (event) => {
        console.log('Received event: ', event);
        const json = JSON.parse(event.data);
        console.log(json);
        this.answers.push(new Answer(json['answer']));
        console.log(this.answers);
        observer.next(this.answers);
      };
      eventSource.onerror = (error) => {
        if (eventSource.readyState === 0) {
          console.log('The stream has been closed by the server.');
          eventSource.close();
          observer.complete();
        } else {
          observer.error('EventSource error: ' + error);
        }
      };
    });
  }
}
```

And HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <p>
      <button (click)="requestAnswerStream()">Gimmie answers</button>
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let answer of answers | async">{{answer.answer}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you do this and tell me if you see anything and  if you do post in your question what you see. `{{ answers | async | json }} `post it outside your `<div class="row"></div?`

Comment: Does your `Answer` class have an `answer` property? You are logging the json to the console but pushing the json.answer to the observable.

Comment: @PatricioVargas it is displaying 'null'

Comment: @BijanRafraf Yes, it has :)

Comment: I think your problem is that you component loads, triggers the asycn pipe, but you haven't requested the answer stream. Can you put this in your ngOnInit()..`requestAnswerStream()` then tell me if `{{ answers | async | json }}` shows something

Comment: @PatricioVargas no, still null value

Comment: @annterina Can u try to subscribe the observable on ngOnInit and check  what you are getting in response. this.answerReactiveService.getAnswerStream().subscibe((response)=>{console.log(response)}); like this

Comment: @JameelM When I do NOT click on my button with requestAnswerStream() I am getting in the console array with one answer, then array with two answers etc. On the other hand, when I first click on the button I can't see any changes in the console

Comment: @annterina I could see one issue that , you are completing the observable sequence on eventSource.error but once you got the data in onMessage ,you emit the value using next but not completing the sequence using observer.complete.

Comment: @annterina I am posting an approach , may be you can try that.

Answer (score 2):

After some research I achieved the result by using ngZone. I found similar problem here: https://blog.octo.com/en/angular-2-sse-and-changes-detection/

and now my service code looks like that and it works correctly:

```
      eventSource.onmessage = (event) => {
        this.zone.run(() => {
          console.log('Received event: ', event);
          const json = JSON.parse(event.data);
          this.answers.push(new Answer(json['answer']));
          observer.next(this.answers);
        });
      };
```

I am just wondering if this solution can be perceived as fully reactive? 
I didn't find any other way to make this work.

Comment: Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36812714/using-rxjs-and-angular-2-in-order-to-deal-with-server-sent-events/48025179#48025179) is an excellent answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a synchronicity issue. `Observable.create` runs synchronously and creates an observable. The callback from your EventSource does get called but its too late to effect that created observable.

The solution is to use a `Subject` which is a member of the service class and will persist until the EventSource callback can effect it. You will have to 'hook-up' the service subject to your component observable in the component's constructor. Then `getAnswerStream()` becomes `triggerAnswerStream()` which sets the Eventsource posting events to the subject.

Something like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-answers',
  templateUrl: './answers.component.html',
  providers: [AnswerReactiveService],
  styleUrls: ['./answers.component.css']
})
export class AnswersComponent {
  answers: Observable<Answer[]>;

  constructor(private answerReactiveService: AnswerReactiveService) {
    this.answers = answerReactiveService.answerStreamSubject.asObservable();
  }

  requestAnswerStream(): void {
    this.answerReactiveService.getAnswerStream();
  }

}
```

and

```
@Injectable()
export class AnswerReactiveService {

  private answers: Answer[] = [];
  private url: string = 'http://localhost:8080/events/1';

  public answerStreamSubject: Subject<Array<Answer>>;

  triggerAnswerStream(): void {
      let url = this.url;
      let eventSource = new EventSource(url);
      eventSource.onmessage = (event) => {
        console.log('Received event: ', event);
        const json = JSON.parse(event.data);
        console.log(json);
        this.answers.push(new Answer(json['answer']));
        console.log(this.answers);
        this.answerStreamSubject.next(this.answers);
      };
      eventSource.onerror = (error) => {
        if (eventSource.readyState === 0) {
          console.log('The stream has been closed by the server.');
          eventSource.close();
          this.answerStreamSubject.complete();
        } else {
          this.answerStreamSubject.error('EventSource error: ' + error);
        }
      };
  }
}
```

Comment: I applied your solution. Almost copy paste, with single change:
public answerStreamSubject: Subject<Array<Answer>> = new Subject<Array<Answer>>();  because of undefined error

and nothing changed...

Comment: it could be that I have missed the `this` in `this.answerStreamSubject`

Comment: No, covered that

Answer (score 0):

Once you got the service result  complete the sequence by using **observer.complete** after emit the value using  **observer.next()**

```
eventSource.onmessage = (event) => {
        console.log('Received event: ', event);
        const json = JSON.parse(event.data);
        console.log(json);
        this.answers.push(new Answer(json['answer']));
        console.log(this.answers);
        observer.next(this.answers);
        observer.complete();
      };
   };
```

Inside component

```
export class AnswersComponent implements OnInit {
  answers: Observable<Answer[]>;

  constructor(private answerReactiveService: AnswerReactiveService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
        this.answerReactiveService.getAnswerStream().subscribe((response)=>{
        this.answers=response;
    });
  }
}
```

And then in Html you can simply iterate the **answers**

```
 <li *ngFor="let answer of answers">{{answer.answer}}</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using - `addEventListener`

An example of which works for me:

```
@Injectable()
export class EmployeeService {

  public employeesBehavior: BehaviorSubject<Employee>;
  public employeesObservable: Observable<Employee>;

  private URL = 'http://localhost:8080';

  constructor() {
    this.employeesBehavior = new BehaviorSubject(null);
    this.employeesObservable = this.employeesBehavior.asObservable();
  }

  public stream() {
    const streamURL = this.URL + '/stream';
    const eventSource = new EventSource(streamURL);

    eventSource.addEventListener('employees', (event: any) => {
      const employee = JSON.parse(event.data) as Employee;
      this.employeesBehavior.next(employee);
    });
  }
}
```

Сomponent

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  public employees: Employee[] = [];

  constructor(
    public employeeService: EmployeeService
  ) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.employeeService.stream();

    this.employeeService.employeesObservable.subscribe(e => {
      if (e != null) {
        this.employees.push(e);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Template

```
<div *ngFor="let employee of employees">
     {{employee.name}}
</div>
```

Server (Spring Boot)

```
@GetMapping(value = "/stream", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<ServerSentEvent<Employee>> stream() {
        return employeeService.stream().delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).map(e ->
            ServerSentEvent.<Employee>builder()
                .id(String.valueOf(e.getId()))
                .event("employees")
                .data(e)
                .build()
        );
    }
```

Comment: Why didn't eventSource.onmessage method not work?